# Calculus: Tangents and Normals

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

The normal at the point $A=(-1,2)$ on the curve $y=3-x^2$ meets the curve again at $B$, find:

(1) The equation of the normal at $A$ and

(2) The coordinates of $B$

(3) Find the coordinates of the point $C$ on the curve where the curve is parallel to the normal at $A$

1 and 2 I understand how to solve, the solution I need is for Q3, coordinates of point C on the curve where the curve is parallel to the normal..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Visit following link for MathJax tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: 1 and 2 I understand how to solve, the solution I need is for Q3, coordinates of point C on the curve where the curve is parallel to the normal...

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should show what you have attempted as well as explaining where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The slope of your curve is given by $$f'(x)=-2x$$ for $x=-1$ we get $$m=-\frac{1}{2}$$ so the equation of our normal line is given by $$y=-\frac{1}{2}x+n$$

Plug the coordintes $$x=-1,y=2$$ into your equation and you will get $n$

Comment: I was going to do an answer, but you basically said all there is to say on this one. Well played. (+1)

Comment: Did you mean to write $m = 2$?